# Why are there two different tags for gin-rummy

Tags: discussion, tags

Wouldn't it be better to have a tag called [gin-rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin-rummy) instead of the two tags [gin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin) and [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy) being used today?
Or is there a difference between the tags [gin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin) and [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy) so that there should be  added a third tag called [gin-rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin-rummy) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't actually have two tags for Gin Rummy, we have just one:

- [gin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin) is the tag for Gin Rummy, because it's sometimes known as simply “Gin”.
- [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy) is the tag for normal (non-Gin) Rummy.

It seems incorrect to use both tags on questions about Gin Rummy.

Let's remove [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy) from Gin Rummy questions, and rename [gin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin) to [gin-rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin-rummy) to increase clarity and make it clearer you don't also need to use [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy) beside that tag. (The rename should probably be done by a diamond moderator, who can do tag renames more cleanly.)

Comment: Who is fixing this?

Comment: @OlaStröm Nobody yet; the meta is less than a day old. We tend to wait a few days before actioning meta to allow time for other voices and for votes. The diamond mods might do the rename but I could just drop the rummy tag off gin-rummy questions myself. (Or you could suggest edits to do so.)

Comment: I like this suggestion and will perform the necessary adjustments in a few days assuming the vote doesn't change drastically.

Comment: @PatLudwig What was the final decision on this?

Comment: @JoeW - thanks for the reminder, this is done.